# PreferenceActivity, hide the length of the password in EditTextPreference

Tags: android, passwords, preferences, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

My actions:

I click on EditTextPreference

A window appears with the password

All is well, but you can see the previously entered length of password

How I can hide the length of the password?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TextColor of the EditText to white. So that whatever the user types in will be invisible and you can also hide the cursor using these

```
android:textColor="@color/white" or  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

Comment: But then if the user wants to enter a new password, they will not see the password already exists, and a new password will be appended to the beginning or end of an existing one, is not the solution.

Comment: I know that can create your own password dialog and define a to it, but maybe there is a solution short.